# Checkbox not checked when clicked in IE 8 and below using knockout binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having an issue with the following checkbox in IE 8 and below not being checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="event: { change: $parent.addOtherAddresses }, attr: { value: $index() + 1 }"  />
```

I'm trying to pass an entire object to 'addOtherAddresses', which it actually does and works fine, however the browser does not show the checkbox as actually being checked.

I've tried other solutions that display the check in the checkbox but only return the id or value of the checkbox, I need the entire parent data object returned so I can do other logic based on whats been checked.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that you're not closing your `data-bind` attribute? Or is that a typo in this post and not copied from your code? - Edit: apparently a typo since it's fixed now.

Comment: It was just a typo from this post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the `change` event handler prevents the default action by the browser because that's what Knockout does by default. If you want to allow the browser's default action, you must return `true` from your handler:

```
event: { change: function() { $parent.addOtherAddress($data); return true; } }
```

Comment: @GPB Give him a head's up by voting up his answer, he helped you after all and it's a useful answer.

Comment: +1 Micheal, your the 'Best' ;) I lost the last 2 hours of my life but with your help, it's now just 2 hours, not more. :) Thank you!

Comment: Just as information Micheal, do you know why preventing default action by the browser don't prevent to change selected radio button in firefox and chrome?

Comment: I don't know why there might be browser differences.